# Popping value from array within function

Tags: python, arrays, gdscript

If I create a function in python that takes in an array and pops a value, will the array be permanently changed outside of the function?

ie

```
func popRandom(array):
    array.shuffle()
    return array.pop()
```

Will the array be permanently altered outside of the function? Because that's what I'm going for.

Comment: Yes mutating an array in the function changes the original (including the `shuffle`). But why not test it yourself?

Comment: Also, python declares functions with `def`, not `func`.

Comment: Ahh that's true. I'm writing it within a big code base and it didn't occur to me to test a small sample in on online IDE or something!!

Comment: Aplet123 that's true, I'm actually using GDScript which uses func instead of def but is otherwise similar to python

Comment: BTW, there's no need to shuffle the array for this. `pop()` takes an optional argument with the index to remove, so you can use `return array.pop(random.randrange(len(array))`

Comment: Barmar is there a speed advantage to that? Personally I feel like it's less readable, but if it's significantly faster than maybe it's worth it?

Comment: @Barmar [random.choice(array)](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.choice) is an even better choice (sic). EDIT: oh yeah my bad that won't remove the item from the list.

Comment: @G.T. shuffling an array has to be much slower than removing one randomly selected element.